# Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) thr

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, junit, mockito

I got this error while i executed my mockito test file,here i have void main and also in the src/main/java i have another main how to resolve this error i have tried this from this website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_first_application.htm and also any suggestions to learn junit+mockito+springboot

I tried this code it should show output as pass but got error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

```
package com.tutorialspoint.mock;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class PortfolioTester {
    
   Portfolio portfolio; 
   StockService stockService;
       
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
      PortfolioTester tester = new PortfolioTester();
      tester.setUp();
      System.out.println(tester.testMarketValue()?"pass":"fail");
   }
   
   public void setUp(){
      //Create a portfolio object which is to be tested     
      portfolio = new Portfolio();      
  
      //Create the mock object of stock service
      stockService = mock(StockService.class);      
  
      //set the stockService to the portfolio
      portfolio.setStockService(stockService);
   }
   
   public boolean testMarketValue(){
           
      //Creates a list of stocks to be added to the portfolio
      List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();
      Stock googleStock = new Stock("1","Google", 10);
      Stock microsoftStock = new Stock("2","Microsoft",100);    
 
      stocks.add(googleStock);
      stocks.add(microsoftStock);

      //add stocks to the portfolio
      portfolio.setStocks(stocks);

      //mock the behavior of stock service to return the value of various stocks
      when(stockService.getPrice(googleStock)).thenReturn(50.00);
      when(stockService.getPrice(microsoftStock)).thenReturn(1000.00);      

      double marketValue = portfolio.getMarketValue();      
      return marketValue == 100500.0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of Mockito and JUnit? Older versions may not do things the correct way as far as modules are concerned.

Comment: I have tried updating the dependencies to latest version but its still not working

Comment: Something you are using has not been updated to work with modern versions of Java (after Java 8). Show us the full stack trace of the exception which might indicate where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider working with mockito annotations also you dont need to declare portfolio globaly since you already instantiated a new one in you method "SetUp".

best approach :

```
@InjectMocks
StockService stockService;
```

also for the setup method :

```
 @Before
 public void setup() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
//
// no need to create the mock object of stock service ,do your test 
// directly in testMarketValue.
   }
```

also please add the test annotation :

```
@test
public boolean testMarketValue(){...}
```

this is the best approche since you want to mock also the code inside your services without writing the hole code again .